# How to get directions from node-googlemaps for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps

I am trying to get this [Google Maps directions on Node.js example](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps/blob/master/test/directions-test.js) to work for the last 24 hours, without any luck. I keep getting **·· √ OK » 2 honored (0.848s)**.

I posted similar question before at [Using node-googlemaps to get direction from google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750462/using-node-googlemaps-to-get-direction-from-google-maps), trying my luck again hopefully I'll get some answers now that i have narrowed down my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading up on Node.js i have realized that [Vows](http://vowsjs.org/) is a behavior driven development framework for Node.js.

Now i feel so stupid trying to run the test codes and thinking vow was just a fancy library the author has used to implement Google Map's Api.

Anyways here's the code to get directions between two coordinates:

```
var gm = require('googlemaps');
var util = require('util');

gm.config('key', '<insert your api key here>');
gm.directions('31.470656,74.412929', '31.470789,74.408619' , 
function(err, data){util.puts(JSON.stringify(data));});
```

Comment: misguiding code: `.directions` expects an object `[params](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests), not two strings